# multiple range comparison in if statement

Tags: java, android

I want to compare multiple parameters  of water quality with its range.
My code only comparing ph value and i want to compare each of the parameter.

Code is here.

```
 private void QualityOfWater(){
    String   Ph_value = ph_value.getText().toString();
    String   ColorHazen = colorHazen.getText().toString();
    String   Other_element= other_element.getText().toString();
    String   Turbidity = turbidity.getText().toString();
    String phlow="6.5";
    String phup="8.5";
    String colorlow="5";
    String colorup="15";
    String turblow="1";
    String turbup="5";
    String otherlow="500";
    String otherup="2000";
    if(Ph_value.compareTo(phlow)>0 && Ph_value.compareTo(phup)<0 ||
        ColorHazen.compareTo(colorlow)>0 && ColorHazen.compareTo(colorup)<0 ||
       Other_element.compareTo(otherlow)>0 && Other_element.compareTo(otherup)<0 ||
       Turbidity.compareTo(turblow)>0 && Turbidity.compareTo(turbup)<0 ){


                   Toast.makeText(this, "water is drinkable.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "water is not for drinking purpose.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
```

Comment: You will use && instead of || operator.

Comment: Your logic won't always work, because you are trying to do numerical comparisons using strings, which won't always be the same width (and zero padded).  Instead, use numbers for comparisons.  That being said, it actually does look like you are comparing all the parameters here.  So, what is your question?

Comment: @Mr.Roshan i have already tried it still it is not working.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen my question is what changes i would have to make in my code so that it start proper comparison of all the parameters

Comment: instead of compareTo method you will use equals() method for comparing the string values.

Comment: @Mr.Roshan i dont know how to use equals()  for range comparission

Comment: may any one suggest some code which i can substitute with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem in your current code is that you are trying to do numerical comparisons using text strings.  This won't work, as strings sort lexicographically, meaning according to dictionary order.  This won't always produce the correct numerical sorting in every case.  Also, I think you want to AND together all your logic, since presumably all these criteria need to be true in order for the water to be drinkable.

```
int ph_value = Integer.parseInt(ph_value.getText().toString());
int colorHazen = Integer.parseInt(colorHazen.getText().toString());
int otherElement = Integer.parseInt(other_element.getText().toString());
int turbidity = Integer.parseInt(turbidity.getText().toString());
int phLow = 6.5;
int phHigh = 8.5;
int colorLow = 5;
int colorHigh = 15;
int turbLow = 1;
int turbHigh = 5;
int otherLow = 500;
int otherHigh = 2000;

if (ph_value > phLow && ph_value < phHigh &&
    colorHazen > colorLow && colorHazen < colorHigh &&
    otherElement > otherLow && otherElement < otherHigh &&
    turbidity > turbLow && turbidity < turbHigh) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "water is drinkable.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "water is not for drinking purpose.",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Also note that I changed your variable names in accordance with Java naming conventions.  Variables start with a lowercase letter, and use camel case to separate words, not underscores.

Comment: Thank you so much @Tim Biegeleisen